# FREAK Descriptor with Opencv Python

Tags: python, opencv, feature-detection, freak

I was trying to implement the FREAK Descriptor in Python using Opencv. Here is the code i'm using:

```
def surf_freak_detect(image,hessianThreshold):
    surfDetector = cv2.SURF(hessianThreshold)
    surfDetector=cv2.GridAdaptedFeatureDetector(surfDetector,50)
    keypoints = surfDetector.detect(image,None) 
    freakExtractor = cv2.DescriptorExtractor_create('FREAK')
    keypoints,descriptors= freakExtractor.compute(image,keypoints)
    del freakExtractor
    return keypoints,descriptors
```

Is this the correct way to **initialise the Freak Descriptor**? By doing a little debugging I found out that the interpreter takes a very long time at Computing the Descriptors and then eventually crashes. The keypoints are detected properly. Weirdly, **it works sometimes** and **sometimes just crashes**!

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this?

Comment: Actually no. I ended up using SURF. It appears that the OpenCV Python version I was using didn't implement wrappers for the FREAK Descriptor. If you still need to use it, you can use it's through the native C++ implementation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the keypoints are detected properly but the program crashes when generating the descriptors it is because the **descriptor region** (which surrounds the keypoint) comes out of the image and there is a **memory access to a position that does not exist**.

You have to somehow limit the operating region for freak descriptors.

Answer (score 9):

There are now Python bindings for FREAK in OpenCV 3.0. Its configuration options are described [here](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/xfeatures2d/doc/extra_features.html?highlight=freak). It seems to be missing documentation of how to actually call it in Python, but you can use it in Python like this:

```
freakExtractor = cv2.xfeatures2d.FREAK_create()
keypoints,descriptors= freakExtractor.compute(image,keypoints)
```

(You have to get the keypoints from a separate feature detector, like you did in your code above.)