# Assertion failed while drawing match Key Points BF BRISK+FREAK

Tags: python, opencv, image-stitching, brisk, freak

I am trying to stitch two images using `BRISK+FREAK`

Here's the code, When I try to draw the matches I get an error

> error: OpenCV(4.1.2) /io/opencv/modules/features2d/src/draw.cpp:225: error: (-215:Assertion failed) i1 >= 0 && i1 < static_cast(keypoints1.size()) in function 'drawMatches'

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

trainImg = cv2.imread('/content/img1.JPG')
trainImg_gray = cv2.cvtColor(trainImg, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

queryImg = cv2.imread('/content/img2.JPG')
queryImg_gray = cv2.cvtColor(queryImg, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

def detectAndDescribe(image, method=None):
    """
    Compute key points and feature descriptors using an specific method
    """
    
    descriptor = cv2.BRISK_create()
    # get keypoints and descriptors
    (kps, features) = descriptor.detectAndCompute(image, None)

    freakExtractor = cv2.xfeatures2d.FREAK_create()
    keypoints,descriptors= freakExtractor.compute(image,kps)

    return (keypoints, features)

method = 'brisk'
feature_extractor = 'brisk'
feature_matching = 'bf'
kpsA, featuresA = detectAndDescribe(trainImg_gray, method=feature_extractor)
kpsB, featuresB = detectAndDescribe(queryImg_gray, method=feature_extractor)

"Create and return a Matcher Object"
createMatcher = lambda crossCheck :  cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_HAMMING, crossCheck=crossCheck)

def matchKeyPointsBF(featuresA, featuresB, method):
    bf = createMatcher(crossCheck=True)
        
    # Match descriptors.
    best_matches = bf.match(featuresA,featuresB)
    
    # Sort the features in order of distance.
    # The points with small distance (more similarity) are ordered first in the vector
    rawMatches = sorted(best_matches, key = lambda x:x.distance)
    print("Raw matches (Brute force):", len(rawMatches))
    return rawMatches

print("Using: {} feature matcher".format(feature_matching))

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,8))

matches = matchKeyPointsBF(featuresA, featuresB, method=feature_extractor)
img3 = cv2.drawMatches(trainImg,kpsA,queryImg,kpsB,matches,None,flags=cv2.DrawMatchesFlags_NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS)
    

plt.imshow(img3)
plt.show()
```

This is the complete error I get

> Using: bf feature matcher Raw matches (Brute force): 1967
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- error                                     Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in ()
> 4
> 5 matches = matchKeyPointsBF(featuresA, featuresB, method=feature_extractor)
> ----> 6 img3 = cv2.drawMatches(trainImg,kpsA,queryImg,kpsB,matches,None,flags=cv2.DrawMatchesFlags_NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS)
> 7
> 8
>
> error: OpenCV(4.1.2) /io/opencv/modules/features2d/src/draw.cpp:225:
> error: (-215:Assertion failed) i1 >= 0 && i1 <
> static_cast(keypoints1.size()) in function 'drawMatches'

Can't seem to know what is going wrong here, found this [OpenCV Sift/Surf/Orb : drawMatch function is not working well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24552590/opencv-sift-surf-orb-drawmatch-function-is-not-working-well) not able to understand how to correct this

Comment: related: https://forum.opencv.org/t/assertion-failed-while-drawing-match-key-points-bf-brisk-freak/3901

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Yes, that's me. Felt best to post on both to get a more clear picture quickly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing `keypoints` from **FREAK** with `features` from **BRISK**:

Take a careful look at the code of `detectAndDescribe`:

```
def detectAndDescribe(image, method=None):
    """
    Compute key points and feature descriptors using an specific method
    """
    
    descriptor = cv2.BRISK_create()
    # get keypoints and descriptors
    (kps, features) = descriptor.detectAndCompute(image, None)

    freakExtractor = cv2.xfeatures2d.FREAK_create()
    keypoints,descriptors= freakExtractor.compute(image,kps)

    return (keypoints, features)  # <------ keypoints from freakExtractor.compute and features from descriptor.detectAndCompute
```

The reported exception looks random, so it was difficult to find the problem...

---

You may implement `detectAndDescribe` as follows:

- Detect the keypoints with BRISK
- Pass the detected keypoints to FREAK
- Returns the output of `freakExtractor.compute`

---

Suggested implementation:

```
def detectAndDescribe(image, method=None):
    descriptor = cv2.BRISK_create()
    kps = descriptor.detect(image) # kps, features = descriptor.detectAndCompute(image, None)
    freakExtractor = cv2.xfeatures2d.FREAK_create()
    keypoints, descriptors= freakExtractor.compute(image, kps)
    return (keypoints, descriptors)
```

Comment: [FREAK Descriptor with Opencv Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14588682/freak-descriptor-with-opencv-python?#answer-33818707) this post specifies a need of separate feature descriptors [BRIEF (Binary Robust Independent Elementary Features)](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.2/dc/d7d/tutorial_py_brief.html) to get the `keypoints` that we need to feed into `FREAK`, since `kps` has to been detected still your solution `kps, features= freakExtractor.compute(image,kps)` will pop an error

Comment: @SanthoshDhaipuleChandrakanth You are right, (I didn't get an error because I didn't my test never reached `FREAK_create` part). I don't know all the limitations. The code works when detecting keypoints using BRISK, and passing the keypoints as input to FREAK. I updated the post, Thank you.